# How do I use and ExpressionTree to access the name of the property in a lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

I'm using the following approach to get the name of a property specified in a lambda by inspecting the resulting ExpressionTree:

```
var name =GetPropertyName<Entity1, Entity2>(x => x.Entity2);

public string GetPropertyName<T, P>(Expression<Func<T, P>> expression)
    {
        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        var propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
        return propertyInfo.Name;
    }

//name is "Entity2"
```

Given the following expression i want to extract the names "Entity2s", "Entity3s" and "Entity4s"

```
var names = GetPropertyNames<Entity1, IEnumerable<Entity4>>(x => x.Entity2s.SelectMany(x => x.Entity3s).SelectMany(x  => x.Entity4s));
```

Comment: LINQPad is a good tool for dumping `Expression` trees and seeing how to disassemble them.

Comment: The more obvious question is "Why?". What are you trying to achieve with this information?

Comment: For the same reason that libraries like entity framework allow devs to specify lambda expressions that are then inspected in order to construct something else, a sql select statement in the case of entity framework. In my case I'm building a framework to allow devs to define a domain using a builder pattern from which I'm dynamically building an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method for extracting the member names from exactly the `Expression` tree you provided. A more generic method should probably be based on an `ExpressionVisitor` subclass.

```
public static List<string> GetPropertyNames<T, P>(Expression<Func<T, P>> fe) {
    var ans = new List<string>();
    var callExpr1 = fe.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    var callExpr2 = callExpr1.Arguments[0] as MethodCallExpression;
    var e2MemberExpr1 = callExpr2.Arguments[0] as MemberExpression;
    ans.Add(e2MemberExpr1.Member.Name);
    var e2MemberExpr2 = (callExpr2.Arguments[1] as LambdaExpression).Body as MemberExpression;
    ans.Add(e2MemberExpr2.Member.Name);
    var e1MemberExpr1 = (callExpr1.Arguments[1] as LambdaExpression).Body as MemberExpression;
    ans.Add(e1MemberExpr1.Member.Name);
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With an ExpressionVisitor it is a simple as

```
 public static List<string> GetPropertyNames<T, P>(Expression<Func<T, P>> expression)
    {
        var visitor = new Visitor();
        visitor.Visit(expression);
        return visitor.Names;
    }

    class Visitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public Visitor()
        {
            Names = new List<string>();
        }

        public List<string> Names { get; }

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            Names.Add(node.Member.Name);
            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }
    }
```